# Package documentation using DocC failing to recognise catalogue

Tags: documentation, swift-package-manager, docc

If I launch an existing Xcode project for a macOS target and create a new DocC catalogue, I get a basic template for a landing page asking for a summary and an overview etc. If I continue by adding a summary and an overview, then generate the documentation, I see the landing page, no problem.

If I repeat these steps for an SPM package, I don't see a landing page. What additional steps do I need to take?

To be specific, I am using cmd+ctrl+shift+D to generate the documentation and the output lists various functions etc, so it works. I just don't see the landing page.

I tried adding the DocC plugin and using the command line to build the documentation instead but the output still generates the basic format, with no  landing page.

The catalogue seems to be ignored? Any help appreciated.

```
swift package --disable-sandbox preview-documentation --target MyTarget
```

Xcode Version 14.0.1
swift-tools-version:5.6

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the plugin: https://github.com/apple/swift-docc-plugin/issues/29

The problem is, that it does not generate the `documentation` directory for some reason.